# Bootstrap multiselect open only the first time - After ajax it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I try to use bootstrap multiselect with jquery ajax. When execute ajax the multi select button it doesn't work. You can see the problem here: http://www.doyleia.com/anazitisi-ergasias in the last multiselect.

ajax code:

```
function runAjax(tags, contracts, educations, towns) {

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.doyleia.com/anazitisi-ergasias?' + tags + '&' + contracts + '&' + educations + '&' + towns,
}).done(function(data){
    // destroy I used it because builded again the multiselect button after ajax
    $('.multi-boot-select').multiselect('destroy');
    var $html = $(data);
    //hide within that object
    $html.find('.form-for-hide').hide();
    $html.find('p.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
    // insert the object
    $('div.load-jobs').html($html);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the ajax like bellow and now it works:

```
function runAjax(tags, contracts, educations, towns) {

$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.doyleia.com/anazitisi-ergasias?' + tags + '&' + contracts + '&' + educations + '&' + towns,
}).done(function(data){
    // destroy I used it because builded again the multiselect button after ajax
    var $html = $(data);
    //hide within that object

    var finalGet =  $html.find('.row-to-take');

    //$html.find('.form-for-hide').hide();
    $html.find('.hidden.alert.alert-danger').removeClass('hidden');

    // insert the object
    $('div.load-jobs').html(finalGet);
});
```

}